# PTM data from bioservices uniprot

Tags: python, database, bioinformatics, bioservices

I want to retrieve Post-translational modifications (PTMs) data from Uniprot via `bioservices`, I am using following script:

```
from bioservices import uniprot

u = uniprot.UniProt()

ptm = u.search("P38903", frmt="xls", include=True, columns="features")
```

and obtain the following outcome:

```
u'Features\nChain (1); Compositional bias (5); Modified residue (2); Sequence conflict (3)\n'
```

What I want to have are the details of "Modified residue (2)" i.e. what type of modifications are these and what are the positions, (optional) references as well.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: you can't do it with bioservices. It doesn't support the the column value [`feature(MODIFIED RESIDUE)`](http://www.uniprot.org/help/uniprotkb_column_names) where the information is hiding.

But you can get the information by using the [Uniprot API](http://www.uniprot.org/help/programmatic_access). The following Python3 snippet gives you info you need:

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=P38903&format=tab&columns=feature(MODIFIED%20RESIDUE)') as response:
    mod_res = response.read().decode()

residues = mod_res.split('\n')[1].split(';')
for residue in residues:
    print(residue.strip())
```

Output:

> MOD_RES 242 242 Phosphothreonine. {ECO:0000244|PubMed:17330950}.
>
> MOD_RES 257 257 Phosphothreonine. {ECO:0000244|PubMed:18407956}.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to obtain the **feature(MODIFIED RESIDUE)** column, provide its name as follows:

```py
from bioservices import UniProt
u = UniProt()
ptm = u.search("P38903",frmt ="xls", include =True, columns="feature(MODIFIED RESIDUE)")
```

Just tested with version 1.7.5

disclaimer:I'm the main author of bioservices